# DRY controller specs with RSpec: repeated expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, dry

I have a lot of conditions and the same expectations in my controller spec:

```
if condition 1 - expect(reponse).to redirect_to same_url
if condition 2 - expect(reponse).to redirect_to same_url
if condition 3 - expect(reponse).to redirect_to same_url
```

RSpec's DRY rules suggests using "context" instead of "if condition".
Ok, there is my controller spec:

```
RSpec.describe MyController, type: :controller do
  describe ".method" do
    context "when wrong hash" do
      it "redirect to error_url" do
        get :method, key: '123', hash: 'wrong_hash'
        expect(subject).to redirect_to error_url
      end
    end
    context "when status is blocked" do
      it "redirect to error_url" do
        get :method, key: '123', hash: valid_hash, status: 'blocked'
        expect(subject).to redirect_to error_url
      end
    end
    context "when status is expired" do
      it "redirect to error_url" do
        get :method, key: '123', hash: valid_hash, status: 'expired'
        expect(subject).to redirect_to error_url
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As i wrote above, i have the same repeating "it should" and the same expectations in multiple conditions. How to "DRY" it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a shared example: http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples

```
RSpec.describe MyController, type: :controller do
  shared_examples "redirects to error_url" do
    it "redirect to error_url" do
      get(:method, path_options)
      expect(subject).to redirect_to error_url
    end
  end

  describe ".method" do
    context "when wrong hash" do
      let(:path_options) { {key: '123', hash: 'wrong_hash'} }
      it_behaves_like "redirects to error_url"
    end
    # ...etc
  end
end
```

Comment: This is hardly more DRY than the original one: you have the same amount of lines, and the same amount of duplication, but now concealed in strings. And you introduced a mystery guest, because it's not clear anymore what the code is doing from the example itself.

Comment: The same amount of lines would be if you have 1-2 conditions. But if you have about 10 conditions and the same tests, it helps. And it's exactly my case.

Comment: PS My real tests are little bigger than in this demo example.

Comment: @bertbruynooghe The point of this is showing that shared example groups are the way to keep RSpec tests DRY. DRY isn't about lines of code. It seemed best to leave the OP's style as-is.

Answer (score 1):

How about the other duplication, the subject code and the description?

```
describe '.method'  
  it{expect{get :method, key: correct_key, hash: wrong_hash}.to redirect_to error_url}  
  ...
end
```

Comment: It's nice example too. Thanks.